# Are carbonated stalactite deposits sedimentary deposits?

Tags: geology, precipitation, sedimentology

Acording to [britanica.com](https://www.britannica.com/):

> **sedimentary rock**, rock formed at or near Earth’s surface by the accumulation and lithification of sediment (detrital rock) or by the
> precipitation from solution at normal surface temperatures (chemical
> rock).

My question is, as carbonated deposits on caves are formed by chemical precipitation, does that mean a deposit of stalactites is a sedimentary deposit?

Or perhaps it is a supergenic deposit?

Comment: I always regarded stalactites & stalagmites as [accretions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/accretion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stalactites are sedimentary deposits though they form by supergenic-like processes. Importantly, the layers within contain historical information about environmental surface conditions. By contrast, a supergenic deposit is the result of remineralization and concentration of one mineral into another, different mineral; more ultra low-grade chemical metamorphism than sedimentary.