# How to genetically classify a weathering mineral or a mineral formed in soil?

Tags: geology, mineralogy, minerals

Coming from [this question and the answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/18172/20559), a proposed genetic classification of minerals:

> **Endogenic: Magmatic, Metamorphic, Hydrothermal.**
>
> **Exogenic: Supergene, Sedimentary.**

My question is how would you describe minerals as chrysotile formed as an alteration product of mafic rocks in surface (weathering), or clays or oxydes formed in soils as diaspore, that forms in bauxites.

Could an alteration or weathering class be added to that classification?

From [this other answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/23121/20559) I would tend to say they can't be supergenic, but they are exogenic.

> By contrast, a supergenic deposit is the result of remineralization and concentration of one mineral into another, different mineral; more ultra low-grade chemical metamorphism than sedimentary.

Perhaps as a mineral resulted from weathering, it should be included in sedimentary environment because weathering is a part of sedimentary cycle?

What is better?

**Diaspore:**

- **Sedimentary**: bauxites.
- **Weathering**: bauxites.
- **Alteration**: bauxites.
- **Supergenic**: bauxites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the answer I received in The Nacked Scientists](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=83535.msg660453#msg660453) I must classify them as supergenic.

> Freedictionary defines supergene processes as "processes of the physical and chemical conversion of mineral matter in the upper parts of the earth’s crust and on its surface through the action of the atmosphere, hydrosphere, and living organisms at low temperatures. They consist in chemical decomposition, solution, hydrolysis, hydration, oxidation, and carbonization".

So my classification will be:

- Magmatic.
- Metamorphic.
- Hydrothermal.
- Sedimentary.
- Supergenic.